# How to prevent a record triggered flow from executing multiple times

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, recordtriggeredflow

I have a flow where when a field called last touch point date is updated in an opportunity, it then offsets creating a task for the opportunity owner by 7 days to remember to follow up.

I am a complete beginner to salesforce/Flows so for all i know there is a much easier and better way to use it.

The issue I am trying to fix is that when the last touch point is updated before the 7 day offset period is over, it will still send the task. Is there an easier method to set this up, or at least a fix for preventing the task from creation if the field is updated before the 7 day period is up?

Comment: you'll need a field that tracks when the `Last_Touch_Point__c` was updated so you can compare against the offset date in the record-triggered flow with scheduled paths condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are always relying on this date field and if it passes 7 days you'll trigger the task follow up creation, is that correct?
If it is, try to search about scheduled triggered flows, they can help you in this specific case and check every day for outdated touch points creating only once the follow up task needed.
[Trailhead for this subject](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/autolaunched-scheduled-flows/schedule-a-flow)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since I'm new the trailhead helps a ton. I really struggled to find relevant trailheads and since I didn't know what I was looking for I went down a bunch of dead ends. Thanks again!